# Member count but without bots (Discord.js Javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make my Discord bot update a locked voice channel with the server's member count, but I can't figure out how to make it filter out bots. I've looked online and tried different things but none seem to work for me. Could anyone help?

This is my code:

```
  let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("703315963583528991");
  let memberCount = myGuild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
  let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get("704843759078211604");
  memberCountChannel.setName('Members: ' + memberCount);
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: myGuild.members.filter is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (/root/onixo/index.js:21:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (/root/onixo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:433:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (/root/onixo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:417:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (/root/onixo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:199:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (/root/onixo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:467:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/root/onixo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:439:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/root/onixo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/root/onixo/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to use `cache` to access the `members` collection

```js
let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("703315963583528991");
let memberCount = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get("704843759078211604");
memberCountChannel.setName('Members: ' + memberCount);
```

Comment: Somehow I only get the amount of users which are currently in a voice channel. Is there something wrong or outdated with this code?

Comment: @julianYaman I just tested it, it works fine, maybe you did not setup your Privileged Gateway Intents? You can change them in the Bot tab of your Application's page. In this case, you'd have to enable the Server Members Intent to be able to grab GuildMember objects of anyone that is not you or the bot you are using to run the code.